# 401 Unauthorized access to url

Tags: ajax, http-headers, basic-authentication

I have the code below to get data from the url but keep getting 401 Unauthorized errors and response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I've check the password and user and both are correct, if i open the url in the browser I'm asked for user and password, just cant pass this with the script, can any one point me in the right direction as to what I have incorrect please

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

if (btn){
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
           ourRequest.open('GET','https://domain.com/services/rest/getAllLocations','true');

ourRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic user:password"); 
ourRequest.withCredentials = false;


ourRequest.onload = function() {
  if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status <400) {
    var data = JSON.parse (ourRequest.responseText);
    createHTML(data);
  }else {
    console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error");
  }
};

ourRequest.onerror = function () {
console.log("Connection Error");
};

ourRequest.send();

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-withcredentials-attribute:

On cross-origin request you need to set `withCredentials=true` to actually send the authorization headers.

Furthermore, see https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-making-a-cors-request:

> In order for this to work, the server must also enable credentials by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header to “true”. See the server section for details.

That is: The error means, that the server doesn't want you to use that resource in a cors request.

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I don't have access to the server to change any settings, is there no other way to do this?

Comment: Can't tell. I would need the full lists of request and response headers. Maybe you just need to add a correct `Origin` header. Then, in some browsers there are means to ignore these security things (e.g. for debugging) but you should not use it on a regular basis. Furthermore, you cannot count on your users having enabled these. Then, there is the possibility of using your own server as a proxy (hackish).

Answer (score 0):

I had it set as true, but it throw up this error

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Response header
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 26 Feb 2017 13:35:31 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:APPSERVER
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=2E4E1646F86E767F4C43D1FE75718D5BF841409F980B163B16919E; Path=/services/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring Security Application"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Request header
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:hpdomain.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36